# refresh environment updated by child process

Tags: .net

My program calls an external tool using `Process.Start`. I just specify the name of the exe, relying on the location being in the `PATH` environment variable. Prior to this, my program checks that the system which includes this external tool is actually installed, and if it isn't, it installs it by running msiexec, again using `process.Start`. This installer modifies the `PATH`, but my second calls fails saying that it cannot find the file, and I believe this is because the updated environment variables are not available for the currently running process.

Is there a way for me to update the current process with the changes to the environment? or is there some way I can determine what changes have been made by the installer and make this available to my new process?

Note that when i start msiexec I have `UseShellExecute = True` as I need to run as administrator. When I start the other exe, I have `UseShellExecute = False`, as I need to read from StandardOutput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
    Dim path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
```

It reads the Path environment variable from the machine settings and writes them to the current process settings.